# Mongoose update value inside array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to update a value inside comments(kommentit) array. I can target the specific comment and update the value, but when there is multiple comments it overwrites all the other comments with the updated one.

```
router.post('/:id/kommentit/:idcomments/reply', function(req, res, next) {
  Restaurant.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: req.params.id
  }, {
    '$set': {
      'kommentit': req.body
    }
  }, {
    new: true
  }, function(err, comment) {
    res.redirect('/ravintolat');
  });
});
```

I have tried it also without the {new: true}. Doesn't do anything. My HTML for the update looks like this:

```
<form action="/ravintolat/<%= ravintolat._id%>/kommentit/<%= ravintolat.kommentit[i]._id %>/reply" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Otsikko" value="<%= ravintolat.kommentit[i]._id%>">
  <input type="hidden" name="otsikko" placeholder="Otsikko" value="<%= ravintolat.kommentit[i].otsikko%>">
  <input type="hidden" name="arvosana" placeholder="Arvosana 1-5" value="<%= ravintolat.kommentit[i].arvosana%>">
  <input type="hidden" name="arvio" placeholder="Kirjoita lyhyt arvio käynnistäsi" value="<%= ravintolat.kommentit[i].arvio%>">
  <input type="hidden" name="lahettaja" placeholder="Nimimerkki" value="<%= ravintolat.kommentit[i].lahettaja%>">
  <input type="text" name="ravintolanvastaus" placeholder="Otsikko">
  <button class="button small" type="submit">Vastaa</button>
</form>
```

First input field is for me just to check if the comment id is correct.

My Schema:

```
var RestaurantSchema = new Schema({
    nimi: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Nimi on pakollinen!']
    },
    osoite: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Osoite on pakollinen!']
    },
    kaupunki: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Kaupunki on pakollinen!']
    },
    puh: {
        type: String
    },
    arvosana: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
    },
    kommentit: [{
        otsikko: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'Otsikko on pakollinen!']
        },
        arvosana: {
            type: Number,
            required: [true, 'Arvosana on pakollinen!'],
            min: [0, 'Yksi on pienin arvosana!'],
            max: 5
        },
        arvio: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'Arvio on pakollinen!']
        },
        lahettaja: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'Lähettäjä on pakollinen!']
        },
        ravintolanvastaus: {
            type: String,
            default: ""
        }
    }]

}, {collection: 'ravintolat'});
```

The value i would like to update after comment is posted is "ravintolanvastaus" inside "kommentit" array.

req.body console.log after trying to update `ravintolanvastaus` field:

```
{ id: '5b70708d7d87da5058e422a6',
  otsikko: 'Another test comment',
  arvosana: '5',
  arvio: 'Very cool',
  lahettaja: 'Test User',
  ravintolanvastaus: 'Nice ' }
```

It does get the right comment id number and it assigns the value to field `ravintolanvastaus`

Comment: Can you add the schema you have in mongoose for that model?

Comment: Schema added...

Comment: `kommentit` is an array of objects. Your update works as expected since you are not providing the key in the array to change. what key from the `kommentit` you want to update? `otsikko, arvosana, arvio ...`?

Comment: I would like to update the `ravintolanvastaus` value.

Comment: can you show the output of `console.log(req.body)`

Comment: Added console.log output

Comment: Does your `kommentit` array will always has length 1??

Comment: Can you provide the console.log of the `req.body` before you call your update? Also same with the result from mongoose in the function ... console.log(err, comment)